# SceneKit Child Physicsbody not moving when parent node is moving

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have 2 simple nodes (2 balls : one above the other and not in contact) each with a physicsbody with the same characteristics. The one below is the parent node, and the one above is a child node.

When I apply a force to the parent node, both nodes are moving but the physicsbody of the child node does not move. I have activated showphysicsshape option, and I see the physicsbody of the child staying in the original place.

Am I missing something ?

```
Class Character3DClass: CharacterClass
{        
    var CharacterNode: SCNNode!
    var CenterBody: SCNNode!

    func InitChar()
    {
        InitBodyParentNode()
        AddCenterBody()
    }

    func InitBodyParentNode()
    {
        CharacterNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: CharacterNode, options: [:]))
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.charge = 0
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.rollingFriction = 0
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.damping = 0
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

        // Affectation des caractéristiques pour la gestion des collisions
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = eNodePhysics.Player.rawValue
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = eNodePhysics.Player.rawValue | eNodePhysics.Ennemy.rawValue
        CharacterNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = eNodePhysics.TileBorder.rawValue
    }

    func AddCenterBody()
    {
        CenterBody = SCNNode(geometry: Level3D.Dot.geometry)
        CenterBody.categoryBitMask = eNodePhysics.PlayerCenter.rawValue
        CenterBody.position = SCNVector3.init(0, 3, 0)
        CenterBody.scale = SCNVector3.init(0.4, 0.4, 0.4)

        CenterBody.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: CenterBody.geometry!, options: nil))
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.charge = 0
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.rollingFriction = 0
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.damping = 0
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

        CenterBody.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = eNodePhysics.PlayerCenter.rawValue
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =  eNodePhysics.PlayerCenter.rawValue
        CenterBody.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = eNodePhysics.NoValue.rawValue

        CharacterNode.addChildNode(CenterBody)
    }
}
```

Comment: is it because your child node has a different Mask than the parent?

Comment: Nope. Tried with the same mask and same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `func resetTransform()` method to make the physics body match it's node, but it will cost some performance : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514782-resettransform